# How can I serialize a nested m2m field to self with django-rest-framework?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have a `User` model that has a `m2m` relation to itself called `friends` and I'm trying to serialize it to see and update the pk's of users that are in the relation.

**models.py**

```
class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    email = models.EmailField('Email', max_length=254, unique=True)
    name = models.CharField('Full Name', max_length=35, unique=True, null=False, blank=False)

    friends = models.ManyToManyField("User", related_name='user_friends', blank=True)
```

**serializers.py**

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    password = serializers.CharField( 
        write_only=True,
        required=False,
        help_text='Leave empty if no change needed',
        style={'input_type': 'password', 'placeholder': 'Password'}
    ) #  for setting the password
    
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('pk', 'email', 'name', 'friends', 'password')

    def create(self, validated_data):
        validated_data['password'] = make_password(validated_data.get('password'))
        return super(UserSerializer, self).create(validated_data)
```

When I go to my API I see the following:

```
{
    "user": {
        "pk": 1,
        "email": "user@gmail.com",
        "name": "User",
        "friends": [
            "http://localhost:8000/user_detailAPI/2/"
        ],
    }
}
```

but I would like for the `serializer` to display each `friend` in a list in a manner like this:

```
{
    "user": {
        "pk": 1,
        "email": "user@gmail.com",
        "name": "User",
        "friends": [
            2
        ],
    }
}
```

Plus if you could let me know how I would be able to add an object to `friends` field using `POST` or `PUT` request it would be nice because I am new to `django-rest-framework` and I feel like this is an important problem.

Comment: https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#dealing-with-nested-objects

Comment: I can't really see anything there about serializing self objects..

Comment: what difference does it make

Comment: when I try: `friends = UserSerializer(many=True)`  I get an `Unresolved refference` error

Comment: you should make additional serializer to serialize friend similar to the example listed in documentation

Comment: Also you are getting friends hyperlinks as you are using HyperlinkedModelSerializer instead of ModelSerializer

Comment: Yes indeed, now it displays correctly, thank you, but how can I update the field for example add `user3` to it and have it appear in my `user1` object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So looks like there is no real way to do that rigth now but there is a workaround which is bascially:

1. Removing m2m field from user model.
2. Creating a helper table called something like `FriendRelationship` with 2 `Foreign Keys` to user model.
3. Getting the friends data from the helper table.

This works as there is no m2m relations present and data is easy to extract.